# upload data on HDFS Periodically

Tags: hadoop

I am working on a project were I will accumulate data in real time. I want to upload that data from my local machine to HDFS periodically. Here frequency will each couple of hours.

Thoughts on my mind is to schedule a batch file to run after 2 hrs periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options :

- Use a cron job.
- If you want this to be more sophisticated you can use Apache Oozie to schedule your jobs.
- If you want this to be done in a distributed, reliable and fault tolerant manner you can use Apache Flume. With Flume you can even collect data directly from the source by writing a Custom Flume Source for your data source without having to first aggregate the data into your local FS and then move it to HDFS.